# How to add input to existing url

Tags: javascript, html, function

So i've been trying to figure out a way to do this for quite a while,

If a person types : "input" -> button's link become exemple.com/input

Here is my html

```
<div class="search-box">
    <form method="get" id="search-index-form" name="myForm" class="clear-block" role="search">
        <input id="userInput" placeholder="Search">
        <button type="submit" id="mylink" href="http://www.exemple.com/" onclick="othername(); changeLink();"><span>search</span></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

And my javascript

```
function othername() {
    var input = document.getElementById("userInput");
}

function changeLink() {
    var link = document.getElementById("mylink");
}
link.setAttribute('href', link + input);
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: you don't put href attribute on a button, href is for an a tag

Comment: You are using `link` outside of the function that it's declared in, among other issues - recommend editing your question and creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so you can see these errors.

Comment: Why is the setAttribute line outside of the functions? You also need to learn about variable scoping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only one function `changeLink` to achieve the desired result and also, use a `baseHref` variable to store the base href using [Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method.

You can call the `changeLink` when the `blur` event is fired. Then, use the `baseHref` and join it with the value from `button` which is retrieved from [`value` property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp) of input element.

```js
let baseHref = document.getElementById("mylink").getAttribute('href');

function changeLink() {
  var input = document.getElementById("userInput");
  var link = document.getElementById("mylink");
  link.setAttribute('href', baseHref + input.value);
  
  console.log('Now the link is: ' + link.getAttribute('href'));
}
```

```html
<div class="search-box">
  <form method="get" id="search-index-form" name="myForm" class="clear-block" role="search">
    <input id="userInput" placeholder="Search" onblur='changeLink();'>
    
    <button type="submit" id="mylink" href="http://www.exemple.com/">
    
    <span>search</span></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change URL by using window-object, e.g.:

```
window.location.href = url + '/' + input
```

or you can to see at this link (javascript location)

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp